# Scheduling UI tasks for after the visual tree has settled down

Tags: wpf, xaml, winrt-xaml, silverlight-5.0

In XAML-based apps, quite often I need to manipulate on-screen elements, resize or move stuff around. The situation arises usually for very custom UI controls.

The timing of stuff loading and data-binding etc. can give rise to irritating timing issues.

Traditionally, my colleagues and I have worked around these problems by 're-dispatching' work to the UI thread so it runs later, when dependent properties are in the 'final' states.

*Is there a better way to do this? What strategies have you found that work?*

The LayoutUpdated event can be very noisy, fine-grained, and deregistering requires forgoing a Lambda for a method and thus not being able to access enclosed variables from the outer logic - its a bit of a 'mare.

**Edit**

I'll give a tangible example. A custom control draws an outline around a face when doing facial recognition, so we're talking totally custom stuff here, nothing XAML does out the box.

The image needs to be scaled and sized and the paths and geometries scaled and sized so its all in alignment.

When programmatically changing the heights and widths of elements, the impact is not immediate, its only once the UI thread is relinquished back to the XAML framework does the rendering subsystems rearrange everything.

Thus, logic that depends upon the changed values needs to run after the framework has rearranged everything, and so this work needs scheduling to occur later on the UI thread, hence resorting to dispatching. It smells.

Many events and virtuals are called at times when requisite data is not yet available. Sometimes, work needs to be done upon data arrival (i.e. property change notification) which is does not typically trigger the XAML layout events. In this case, we resort to dispatcher hacks.

Answer (score 0):

What about using the `Loaded` event?:

```
Loaded += LoadedHandler;

...

private void LoadedHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Do something here when controls have loaded
}
```

Comment: Hi Sheridan, thanks for your answer. I've added some more detail to illustrate the more complicated and nuanced circumstances under which 'dispatcher hacks' are required.

Comment: I'm a little bit embarrassed about my answer now. :) That's all a bit too much for me, but the only thing that I can suggest is for you to take a look at the [WPF Control Development Unleashed](http://www.adorkable.us/books/wpf_control_development.pdf) book. There might be something in chapter 12 that might help... bit of a long shot. It's a good book, so it might be worth a look anyway.

Comment: Please don't be embarrassed, you were trying to help and the `Loaded` event is a perfectly good place to do things. I wasn't clear in my question.

Comment: It was a light hearted comment, but thanks for your concern anyway. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that in WPF, this dependency property metadata argument exists to help with the problems I'm talking about.

```
FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender
```

The enum doesn't exist in Windows Store applications, presumably since its designers think the `InvalidateArrange` method is a suitable alternative.

Possibly, we should be a) invalidating the arrangement within our DP change handlers b) making these arrangements over multiple passes c) tolerating incorrect layout in-between passes.

Still, the using lambdas with the dispatcher is nice since variables used in calculations can be referenced from inside the closure.